# How do include cython files in python meson-managed project?

Tags: python, cython, meson-build

How do I properly include cython source files in a python meson project managed by the meson build system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cython as a first class language is [still in progress](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/pull/8706) (I'm the author of that work), right now the right way is with a generator or custom target, then compile an extension module:

```
pyx_c = custom_target(
  'cython_file.c',
  output : 'cython_file.c',
  input : 'cython_file.pyx',
  command : [cython, '@INPUT@', '-o', '@OUTPUT@'],
)

import('python').find_installation().extension_module(
  'my_extension_module'
  pyx_c,
  install : true
)
```

[Here's an example from the meson test suite](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/tree/master/test%20cases/python/3%20cython), which is pretty close to my example above.

EDIT: cython as a first class language has landed. So if you can rely on Meson 0.59.0, you can just do:

```
import('python').find_installation().extension_module(
  'my_extension_module'
  'cython_file.pyx',
  install : true
)
```

Comment: I just [published](https://gitlab.gnome.org/tallero/listview-example) a complete application example for my use case (pygobject)! there were many steps missing! 
Some were meson-related, other flatpak related, check the diffs for the `wip/cython` MR if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found (completely code-side) was to add them like any other source file and when you need to import them in a python file

just add

```py
from pyximport import install
install(language_level=3)
```

before importing.

*Best way* is @dcbaker's though. I wrote an example pygobject cython application to show that [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/tallero/listview-example).

Comment: That seems like the wrong answer. It adds a runtime dependency on Cython (and pyximport is really only suitable for simple cases with few dependencies or customisation). I'd think a better answer would build them once and distribute the built files like distutils does.

Comment: building and cythonizing the modules with meson was the primary objective but I found no working examples. I haven't encountered any problem so far.